# Hadoop 2.7.1 wordcount job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I installed hadoop 2.7.1 and setup the HDFS ..running on JDK 8  . While attempting to run the wordcount job . I get the below exception . Any help appreciated .

I drilled down to the logs and found .

```
2016-01-02 20:42:17,220 INFO [AsyncDispatcher event handler] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.TaskAttemptImpl: Diagnostics report from attempt_1451788850721_0002_m_000000_3: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1451788850721_0002_01_000010
Exit code: 9009
**Exception message: 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command**,
operable program or batch file.
'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=9009: 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Shell output:         1 file(s) moved.
```

Comment: Please copy paste the "hadoop jar" command you are running

Comment: hadoop jar wordcount.jar com.hadoop.wordcount.WordCount /usr/path/text.txt /usr/file/wordcount

Comment: Can you paste the code you have in the WordCount program? Probably you are trying to connect to database as part of your code.

Comment: No there is no database connection it is just a wordcount job . The file is submitted to HDFS . No dependency to any jdbc code

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is not installed or `MYSQL_HOME` is not set in Environment Variables. Install MySQL or/and set the variable.

Comment: I have MySQL installed in the machine and it is in classpath . When I open a command prompt I can run 'mysql' command but once I run the Hadoop command then 'mysql' is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

external variables are case sensitive, because "MySQL" and "mysql" are differents. Type MySQL in command line, see the result.

**Note:** export enviroment variable and executed jar must be from same user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change MySQL paths in `path` variable to avoid spaces and some uncommon symbols like '&' in it.

I changed

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5
```

to

```
C:\PROGRA~2\MySQL\MYSQLF~1.5\
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP
```

to

```
C:\PROGRA~2\MySQL\MYSQLF~1.5\DOCTRI~1\
```

and this solved my problem.